# issues with interface implementation in c#

Tags: c#, interface

I have the following interface in my code

```
public interface IDevTestable
{
    bool RunTest(out List<Result> selfTestResults);
}
```

I have 4 different classes implementing the interface:

```
class A: IDevTestable
{
    public bool RunTest(out List<Result> selfTestResults)
    {
     //get value1 
    }
}

class B: IDevTestable
{
    public bool RunTest(out List<Result> selfTestResults)
    {
      //get value2
    }
}

class C: IDevTestable
{
    public bool RunTest(out List<Result> selfTestResults)
    {
       //get value3 
    }
}

class D: IDevTestable
{
    public bool RunTest(out List<Result> selfTestResults)
    {
      //get value4 
    }
}
```

When I loop over all the Assemblies in my code, and find the ones that implement the interface to try to call the **RunTest** method, it always runs the first implementation regardless.

How do I select a specific implementation that I would like to run at a given time from the code?

This is how I'm running the code to get all the implementations of an interface:

```
//dev is the driver name that has the implementation. I checked that I got all the driver names correctly. 
foreach (object dev in Devices)
{
    IDevTestable obj = dev as IDevTestable;

    if (obj != null)
    {
       retVal = obj.RunTest(out indvTestResults);
    }
}
```

Every time it is only running the implementation by Class A. Any suggestions on what I might be missing, or could possibly add to make it run the specific implementation that I want it to run?

Comment: creating an interface just so you can test? That means you are almost certainly  going about it the wrong way...

Comment: It's unclear what you ask.What are the `Devices`, etc.?

Comment: Does Devices only contains of objects of class A (what you call "first implementation")?

Comment: 'Devices' is a List<object> of all the objects present. It will give me a list of drivers that are used in my code. It is not restricted to only Class A. 
Yes, they are all public methods, I apologize. Just updated it.

Comment: How is the list populated? Are you sure that there are objects of type `B`, `C`, or `D` in the list?

Comment: Show the code where you fill the `Devices` list. If there's a `B` instance in there, it surely won't run the `A` implementation for that. How do you verify which implementation is run?

Comment: What does "it always runs the first implementation regardless" mean? When `dev` is class `B`, what happens exactly? I understand you are saying that `A.RunTest` is called, which would be impossible...

Comment: I don't have the code that populates the list as it's proprietary to another organization. However, I can view the elements present in the list when I debug the code, and it gets populated with all the different instances (A, B, C, D etc.). Just as Andrew mentioned, when I debug the code it runs `A.RunTest` everytime, even when `dev` is class `B, C or any other class`. 
The way I've been debugging it is to force return values from every test, and what I observed was the 'A.RunTest' return value is being returned every time.

Comment: As a separate point, take a look at unit testing.  It's better than implementing actual tests in your code.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx

Comment: Thanks PeteGO, I ran the unit tests, and they seem to be calling into the code as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I select a specific implementation that I would like to run at a given time from the code?

When you ask this, you mean how object dynamic bindings are made? You don't need to explicitly call the method implemented in one of your classes.. just need to create the object of that type the rest is done by itself.

You don't say how the list is populated but, I imagine populating it something like this

```
Devices.Add(new A());
Devices.Add(new B());
Devices.Add(new C());
Devices.Add(new D());
```

Also, if you're sure that every device implements your interface IDevTestable you should better define the list as

```
List<IDevTestable>
```

rather than

```
List<object>
```

just to make sure no foreign type objects are put in the list..

```
IDevTestable obj = dev as IDevTestable;
```

obj will be null in case dev is not an instance of a class implementing IDevTestable.